# which version of weblogic server does not create _wls_cls_gen.jar?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

because this _wls_cls_gen.jar creates problem for reading properties or xml files inside WEB-INF/classes folder. I have tried with 10.3.4 but no luck. Could anyone tell which version they have fixed this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the Filtering Classloader.  Also, 10.3.4 includes the ClassLoader Analysis Tool that can help you configure it: https://blogs.oracle.com/jeffwest/entry/weblogic_1034_classloader_analysis_tool

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the info, but I'm trying to resolve the following issue by upgrading to latest version of weblogic server rather than modifying the code. Will classloader resolve this?
http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=408

Comment: The filtering class loader is configured using the weblogic.xml and/or weblogic-application.xml deployment descriptors.  I do not know if it will fix the problem but it is worth a try.